# Dropdown com SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Estou com uma arte e agora ela está em um arquivo SVG. O problema é que o cliente quer que ao passar o mouse (ou se clicar) em um bloco, ele deve abrir um menu. Não sei se tem a possibilidade de criar isso, mas queria saber. O código SVG que tenho hoje: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpwmdE

Comment: No click você quer que abra um menu ? ou quer que redirecione para uma pagina com um menu?

Comment: Dá sim e fica maravilhosamente belo. Tem esse exemplo aqui com SVG: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/ Procure também o Pie Menu Generator (SVG). Tem esse B4D455 aqui: http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/ Tem a resposta da Ana no SOF em Inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132864/creating-a-radial-menu-in-css Tem um monte de coisa. Se foi possível criar o Highcharts, claro que dá pra fazzer um menu.

Comment: Eu tenho o arquivo SVG, o que preciso é que ao passar o mouse em um <path> abra um submenu ao lado tipo com um postion relative/absolute. Esse ta sendo maior problema e o pessoal da agência tem que entregar para o cliente ;/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Quero que abra um menu ao lado. Por exemplo, se eu clicar no "6" vai abrir um menu do lado dele, no lado esquerdo

Comment: Você deseja fazer [isso](http://comunicacaointerage.com.br/paginas/DiskBanner/diskbanner.html) com SVG?

Comment: @Randrade Na verdade o SVG já tento certinho. Só quero criar um dropdown ao passar o mouse no elmento <path>

Comment: Opa, já conseguiu?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que talvez tenha resolvido seu problema, fiz assim:

Adicionei uma div, que contém os menus fora do seu SVG e coloquei todos os 6 menus dentro dela, com `display: hidden` no CSS e tomei a liberdade de escolher cores básicas. Assim, você tem total controle visual (seja alterando o HTML ou o CSS) do menu.

Fiz também um pequeno código jQuery para ativar/desativar a visualização dos menus após o clique para o usuário. Ele irá carregar o submenu na tela exatamente na posição que o usuário clicou.

Aqui se encontra o código: https://jsfiddle.net/p4ypat03/4/

Espero ter ajudado.